# Conditional method call in threadfirst

Tags: clojure

I have an java object that I'm calling various builder methods on. I want some of the methods to be called in certain situations. This should look something like:

```clj
(def connect-params (-> (ConnectParam/newBuilder)
                        (.withHost  (env :host))
                        (.withPort  (env :port))
                        (if (not (= (env :environment) "dev"))
                            #(.withAuthorization % (env :user) (env :password))
                            identity)
                        (.build)))
```

The problem with this is that the thread first macro pushes the builder as the first argument to the `if` condition - which is obviously not the intent. I believe I can write a macro to evaluate the inner condition first, but I think there should be some elegant functional way of doing this without macros. I don't want to use a `let` statement and build by incrementally calling methods because I think its inelegant. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can also mix `->` and `cond->` like the following:

```
(-> (ConnectParam/newBuilder)
    (.withHost (env :host))
    (.withPort (env :port))
    (cond-> (not (= (env :environment) "dev"))
            (.withAuthorization (env :user) (env :password)))
    (.build))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
(def connect-params (-> (ConnectParam/newBuilder)
                        (.withHost  (env :host))
                        (.withPort  (env :port))
                        (#(if (not (= (env :environment) "dev"))
                            (.withAuthorization % (env :user) (env :password))
                            %))
                        (.build)))
```

where you wrap the `if` inside a call to an anomnymous function: `(#(if ...))`. The thread-first macro will insert the evaluation of the preceding forms as the first argument to that function call.

Comment: Using `(#(..))` is a good hack but I think in this case `cond->` is preferable